# Download entire Ubuntu One folders from the web client?

Tags: ubuntu-one, downloads, cloud

Since U1's being axed and the desktop client can't connect, how should I about downloading large numbers of files in nested folders from the web client?

I'd prefer to not install Chrome.

Comment: Why can't the desktop client connect? Seems to be working just fine here, in any case.

Comment: Little clue; it's been acting very poorly for the past few months, and has flat-out refused to do squat since February.

Comment: Well, I just completed a sync after reading your comment. Perhaps you might want to give it a go?

Answer (score -1):

use firefox, [flashgot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashgot/) and [uget](http://ugetdm.com/), or any download manager that you like that is capable of handling large files, pausing and resuming, never use the built in download manager of any browser, it will damage your files

Comment: why  dowvotes? maybe I can edit my answer to make it better

Answer (score -1):

You could do what I did: use a service like [Otixo](http://otixo.com/) and move your data from cloud to cloud if you have any other cloud service.

Comment: That service looks like they require your accounts details for every cloud you want to use with them.

Comment: Right, but you can revoke access any time

Comment: I didn't look very carefully but I am always wary of that kind of service - keep in mind you have t tell them your credentials - and they just promise to keep them confidential and delete them when you terminate.

Comment: You DON'T have to tell them your username/password. All of these services use oAuth or some similar protocol, so otixo only has a token which can be revoked at any time.

Comment: I see - as I said I didn't look into it carefully enough - thx for pointing this out :-))

Comment: I think it is the fastest way to save your data, you can still download it later, but till then, it is in a safe place. (I recommend using google drive anyway, it has an awesome ubuntu client, called insync)